# Why Bootstrap's creators not using the normal classes in the new themes site?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap creator just annonuce a new site http://themes.getbootstrap.com/ which using bootstrap and need to be a "stunning real world examples" of using bootstrap (http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/)

so when looking at the source code I was excepting to see some "rows" "span-12" and all the known classes names excpet what I see is this classes names:

```
dv alm dz
k
di
```

and so on

any good reason why not just using the normal names? and how they do it? like if they not using all the rows and span how they using the grid than?

Comment: @Darth_Vader html is public.. I did not meant to "steal" their design, just  understand the reason

Comment: My wild guess is that they don't want newbies copy/pasting right from their demo site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *"are using"* the normal bootstrap classes. Although I do not know the exact process, it looks as if they're *["mangling"](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/mangle)* the CSS selectors of Bootstrap much like what happens you minify and uglify your JavaScript source. When you mangle your JS local variables and functions will get renamed from something like `isRightClick()` to `d()`.

**Why do you do this?**

To reduce the footprint of your static resources. Instead of using `.col-md-12` or `.col-md-6 .some-class` multiple times in their CSS file it's reduced to `.a` and `.a .b`. Which is a lot smaller.

There could be other reasons like a preventative measure of some sort.

**How do they know which classes to use then?**

More than likely they are using something like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or some other process that runs in the background when they make updates or are ready to deploy the project. Whatever they use, it is likely performing some sort of replacement, whether that be variables or a find-n-replace approach I have no clue. But they probably write something like this:

```html
<div class="{{row}}">
    <div class="{{col-md-6}} {{col-lg-4}}"></div>
</div>
```

Which at some point is converted to:

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b c"></div>
</div>
```